# Get <tr> id via input value keyup

Tags: get, html-table

html code :

```
<tr id="myname">
<td><input class="count" type="text" value="1"></td>
</tr>
```

jquery code :

```
$('input.count').keyup(function(e){
        var test = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
        alert(test);
    });
```

when keyup input , get tr id !

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please reword your question, it is unclear what exactly you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method in jQuery:

```
$('input.count').keyup(function(e){
    var test = $(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
    alert(test);
});
```

Here's a working example: [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UcCeW/25/)

What's different is that you haven't provided the `<table></table>` tags.